# "undefined reference to `floorf'" error even with "-lm" flag

Tags: c, gcc, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Using the floorf function from math.h library in my code results in the "undefined reference to `floorf'" error. I already edited my tasks.json to include the "-lm" flag file like this:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc-9 build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc-9",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-lm"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Generated task by Debugger"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

However, nothing has changed and I'm still getting the error.

I'm using WSL in Vscode.

EDIT: Here's the error output:

```
Build finished with error:

/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccg38t0m.o: in function `fill1d':
/home/viktor/upr/cosSim.c:51: undefined reference to `floorf'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1).
enter code here
```

Comment: Try building it from command line

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a full and complete copy-paste (as text and without modifications) of the error output.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude done

Comment: Do you also have output of the command actually being used to build your program? It does show `-lm` being used?

Comment: It doesn't show the command at all, the only thing I see in the command line is "> Executing task: C/C++: gcc-9 build active file <". I also tried building it directly from command line as @EugeneSh. suggested and that seemed to work fine.